# bootstrap carusel control remains white color after clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with bootstrap carusel-control arrows that change the slides on click. When I click on the arrow on the phone its opacity holds to the value of 1, the default opacity of the arrows is 0.5(when the arrow is not hovered nor it is clicked). I want the carusel-control Arrow to remain opacity 0.5 after being cliked. On the Pc it is solved by the following code:

```
.carousel-control:focus{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

but on the phone it does not work.
I have an example link, but for unknown to me reasons the code above doesnt work on that example: https://jsfiddle.net/borovec/psrxt7ay/25/

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Try to run this on local: https://jsfiddle.net/pxovc3js/
Is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes on local it works on PC, but on the phone the opacity of the arrows remains 1.

Comment: Did you try to emulate the code on mobile view with F+12 ? Because it looks like it's working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below CSS:

```
.carousel-control:focus, .carousel-control:hover {
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
}

.carousel-indicators{
  display: none;
}

.row-1{
  margin-top:-7vw;
}
```